# Compute stats function on non-overlapping day-wide time window with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series

## Preamble

How can I apply a function to a list with non-overlapping sliding window. E.g. `data  = {x_1, x_2, ...., x_n}` and we apply f with window size 2 to get `{f(x_1,x_2), f(x_3, x_4), ...., f(x_{n-1}, x_n)}`.

I understand that I can partition and use map on the partitioned list. But are there more efficient ways to handle this operation, especially for ndarray and dataframe? Something that would analogous to `BlockMap` of Mathematica.

## Question

The ultimate goal of this is: suppose the dataframe is a time series with values for each hour of the day. How can I apply a function (e.g. mean, variance) for each day, i.e. function blockmaps with a non-overlapping window of 24 hour size?

**EDIT 1**:
Here is a code that returns a pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dat = np.random.uniform(0,10,40)
xpd = pd.DataFrame(dat)

xpd.rename(columns = {0:'new_name'}, inplace = True)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018 03:00:00', periods=40, freq='H') 
xpd.set_index(date_rng, inplace=True)
```

How can I calculate the variance for each day, i.e. from hourly data, and return as a dataframe. 
I tried the below line but it didn't work:

```
xpd.groupby(by=lambda x: pd.Series.dt.floor(x, freq='d'))
```

**EDIT 2**
This worked, problem seems to be solved:

```
xpd.groupby(by=lambda x: x.floor('d')).var()
```

Comment: how do you want to handle the case when `n % 2 != 0`?

Comment: @norok2 Let's assume it's even, or just pad with the same value right and left.

Comment: That is not another variation, it is a completely different question, unless you have a constant time step and you can rely on the number of rows. You should probably ask a new question.

Comment: @norok2 yes, the time step is constant indeed.

Comment: Then please update the question with all the details, e.g. how to extended this to an arbitrary window size and that eventually you would like to compute e.g. mean, variance, etc. The details about 24 hour size and constant time step should be more a corollary to this.

Comment: What is the window size?

Comment: The floor function takes care of one day window.

Comment: OK, cool. but the question as it stands now, does not have anything to do with the title (or the first part of the question).

Comment: Yes, it was not well defined.

Comment: Note that `floor('d')` may or may not be using a constant window, for the first and last blocks, like in the sample code you provide.

Comment: Yes, that part need to be thought out so as to keep that statistics meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(EDIT: Answered when was without edits and titled: **map a function with non-overlapping window on a dataframe or ndarray**).

---

One way, assuming that `n` is always even, is:

```py
def pairwise_map(func, items):
    iterators = [iter(items)] * 2
    return map(func, zip(*iterators))


list(pairwise_map(sum, range(10)))
# [1, 5, 9, 13, 17]
```

This consists of two steps: the separation in *group* and the mapping.
A more general version of the *group* separation can be found in [`flyingcircus.base.group_by()`](https://pypi.org/project/flyingcircus/).
(Disclaimer: I am the main author of the package).

---

While the above works for the general case, if you have a NumPy array `arr` and the function `func()` is vectorized, one can simply use:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(10)


def func(x, y):
    return x + y


func(arr[::2], arr[1::2])
# array([ 1,  5,  9, 13, 17])
```

---

## EDIT

This can be generalized to any size, e.g.:

```py
def pairwise_map(func, items, window=2):
    iterators = [iter(items)] * window
    return map(func, zip(*iterators))


list(pairwise_map(sum, range(10), 3))
# [3, 12, 21]
```

This obviously rely on `func()` being able to accept the correct or a variable number of arguments.

---

Similarly, for NumPy arrays and NumPy-aware functions:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(9)


def func(*args):
    return sum(args)

window = 3
func(*(arr[i::window] for i in range(window)))
# array([ 3, 12, 21])
```

Note that this require `len(arr) % window == 0`.

---

For NumPy functions that support the `axis` keyword (e.g. `np.mean()`, `np.std()`, etc.), one can simply use the following reshaping trick:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(56)
window = 8
np.mean(arr.reshape(-1, window), axis=1)
# array([ 3.5, 11.5, 19.5, 27.5, 35.5, 43.5, 51.5])
```

Note that this also strictly requires `len(arr) % window == 0`, which can be enforced with e.g. `np.concatenate()` to pad zeros at the end of the input:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(53)
remainder = len(arr) % window
padder = np.zeros(window - remainder if remainder else 0, dtype=arr.dtype)
window = 8
np.mean(np.concatenate((arr, padder)).reshape(-1, window), axis=1)
# array([ 3.5 , 11.5 , 19.5 , 27.5 , 35.5 , 43.5 , 31.25])
```

Comment: I added one more corollary question to the one above.

Comment: @AlGuy It's a completely different question, it is not a clarification.

Comment: Bur wouldn't this approach would create problems when the window size is large?

Comment: @AlGuy Not particularly, but with NumPy arrays and NumPy functions supporting an `axis` keyword, you are better off with a different approach.